# Mulitple Instances of Lightning Component cause some to to not load

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I currently have setup in my org the following component structure

- Base Component
  - $A.createComponent [`c:AutocompleteLookup`]
  - Inline [Component B]
    - Inline aura:iteration [`c:AutocompleteLookup`]

`c:AutocompleteLookup` will work if I don't do the `aura:iteration` and only create it once in the base component dynamically.

If I use `aura:iteration` then the  `c:AutocompleteLookup` component still loads in the base component but some of the attributes for the `lightning:input` are missing and the onchange event no longer fires. However the `aura:iteration` instances of the component `c:AutocompleteLookup` work perfectly and all attributes exist and the onchange events fire.

Any thoughts on the best way to resolve this?

```
<!-- Visualforce Markup -->
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStyleSheets="false">
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
    <div id="lightning" />
        <script>
            $Lightning.use("c:ConsoleFilterTestApplication", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent(
                    "c:BaseComponent",
                    {},
                    "lightning", 
                    function(cmp) {
                    });
            });
        </script>
</apex:page>    

<!-- Lightning App Markup -->
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:BaseComponent"/>
</aura:application>    

<!-- Markup for Extended Base Component -->
<aura:component>
    <!-- Informs the filter its a isOptionB component -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.isOptionB}"/>

    <div class="slds-p-top--small slds-col slds-size--1-of-6">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label slds-p-left--large" for="select-01">Group By: </label>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size--5-of-6">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-p-left--small slds-form-element__control--width">
            <div class="slds-select_container">
                <select id="groupBy-select-field" aura:id="groupBy-select-field" class="slds-select" onchange="{!c.selectChange}">
                    <option>Option A</option>                                
                    <option>Option B</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>

<!-- Markup for BaseComponent -->
<aura:component extends="c:componentWrapper" extensible="true">
{!v.body}
<div class="slds-grid slds-nowrap">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-1">
        {!v.autoCompleteComponent}
    </div>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.check}">
            <c:ComponentB  ###ATTRIBUTESREMOVED### />                   
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <c:ComponentC ###ATTRIBUTESREMOVED###  />                   
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>  
</div>



<!-- Controller for Base Component -->
$A.createComponent(
    "c:AutocompleteLookup",
    autoCompleteAttributes,
    function(newLookup, status, errorMessage){
        console.log(status, errorMessage, newLookup);
        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.autoCompleteComponent", [newLookup]);
            newLookup.addHandler("AutocompleteLookupEvent", component, "c.handlePropertySelection");
        } else if (status === "ERROR") {
            console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
        }
    }
);

<!-- Markup for Component Wrapper -->
<aura:component extensible="true">
    <aura:attribute name="valueAA" type="String" />
    {!v.body}
</aura>

<!-- Markup for Component B -->
<div>
    <aura:iteration items={!v.a} var={result} />
        <aura:iteration items={!result.b} var={secondResult} />
            <c:AutocompleteLookup ##ATTRIBUTESREMOVED## />
        </aura:iteration>
    </aura:iteration>
</div>

<!-- Markup for AutocompleteLookup -->
<div>
    <lightning:input aura:id="{!v.auraIDForLInput}" type="text" name="LightningLookup" label="{!v.label == null ? 'Lookup' : v.label}"
        class="{!(v.inline ? 'inlineMode ' : '') + (v.label == null ? 'hideLabel' : '')}" value="{!v.searchValue}" onchange="{!c.onSearchChange}" placeholder="{!v.placeholder}" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code so that we can help you out.

Comment: @Praveen updated with excerpts from code

Comment: I tried the basic version of what you described(i only had the lighting:input in the autocompletelookup component) and its works fine(All the attribute values are properly binded to the respective lightning:input).

Comment: Issues like these requires enough code so that we can copy past and check its behaviour at our end.If you throw us enough code with static inputs we might help you better.

Comment: Gotcha. I gotta cleanse it so it might take a little while but ill put together a much more complete picture of it. Yea its strange the onchange doesn't fire and the placeholder doesnt get set on mine but it renders the input

Comment: I added additional markup that encompasses all the quirks of the application. VF base, tons of extends, if statements, and iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a order of operations issue. had to render the dynamic version of c:AutocompleteLookup through the renderer to bypass the order of operations bug.